# What is the difference between an instance method used to rename an object and a setter method?

Tags: ruby, oop, methods, instance, setter

If I want to rename my `jedi` object below, why would I create an instance method named `rename` that uses the setter method `name=`? Why not just use the setter method `name=' directly?

Why do this:

```rb
     class Skywalker
       attr_accessor :name

       def initialize(name)
         @name = name
       end

       def rename(new_name)
         self.name = new_name
       end
     end

     jedi = Skywalker.new('Anakin')
     puts jedi.name
     jedi.rename('Luke')
     puts jedi.name
```

When you could just do this:

```rb
     class Skywalker
       attr_accessor :name

       def initialize(name)
         @name = name
       end
     end

     jedi = Skywalker.new('Anakin')
     puts jedi.name
     jedi.name = 'Luke'
     puts jedi.name
```

Both code snippets above do the same thing, so I'm wondering if there is a situation where it would be useful to have the instance method `rename` in addition to the setter method `name=`. Because to me it looks like they are redundant.

Comment: You indeed don't need them both at the same time. You might want to prefer one or the other because of readability (whichever expresses your intent better)

Comment: Note that you could replace your definition of `rename` with `alias :rename :name=` (though as @Sergio says, there's no point in having both).  Whether you want to write `instance.name = ...` or `instance.rename(...)` is purely subjective. If `jedi = Skywalker.new('Anakin')`, `(jedi = 'Bob').upcase #=> "BOB"` may look a little odd when compared to `jedi.rename('Bob').upcase #=> "BOB"`, but both get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#rename` hides the implementation details. You expose a clean and explicit interface - an object can be renamed, but the caller doesn't have to care how it's done. I would recommend to use `attr_reader :name` instead of `attr_accessor :name` to avoid exposing the setter.

If you expose just `#name=` you let the caller to change object internals. It may cause the future changes harder (e.g. if you move `name` to a separate object).

Comment: "you let the caller to change object internals" - not necessarily. It's just a method, same as `rename`. If one were to move storage of `@name` somewhere else, this public api doesn't need to go. I agree that `rename` probably conveys the intent slightly better, but is it worth the effort? It's up to OP to decide :)

Comment: You're right, setter is just a metod. Still `rename` sounds better :)